# Angular 2 get json data and define it as new array in component

Tags: json, angular, http, angular-httpclient

I got my json file and I am getting it on the service. Then I am trying to subscribe to it in the component, but in `console.log(this.jsonObj)` I get empty array. Also if I write `console.log(data)` - I get json data.

Service :

```
objUrl = 'assets/jsons/obs.json';
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  console.log('Hello ObjectsProvider Provider');
}
getObjectsJson() {
  return this.http.get(this.objUrl);
}
```

Component :

```
jsonObj = {};
this.object.getObjectsJson().subscribe((data =>
  this.jsonObj = data
))
console.log(this.jsonObj)
```

Comment: Change jsonObj = {} to jsonObj = [] if your return JSON is array of objects.

Comment: object is not assignable to type []any

Comment: Also notice that `this.object.getObjectsJson().subscribe((data =>
  this.jsonObj = data
))` should be `this.object.getObjectsJson().subscribe(data => {
  this.jsonObj = data
});`

Comment: Use Observable Object instead of normal object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> #### Issue

You are trying to get the `Asynchronous` data in `Synchronous` fashion. You are logging the data `console.log(this.jsonObj)` outside of Observable. So it will get executed without waiting for the result to come from API.

> #### Fix

Just move the log or any code you want to execute the after API inside `subscribe`. So you your code will look like

```
jsonObj = [];
this.object.getObjectsJson().subscribe((data =>
  this.jsonObj = data;
  console.log(this.jsonObj);  //<-- data will be appear here.
))
```

Comment: Yes but when I try to get it in html, it doesnt work, bcs html loads faster then jsonObj

Comment: It will work, whenever the value of `jsonObj` changes, Angular will makes change in UI even the html is already rendered before.

Comment: I get error in ngfor="let i of jsonObj" - cannot find differ[Object Object]. - in console I see 8 objects.

Comment: Initialize array as  `jsonObj = [];`. Answer is corrected as well.

Comment: when I write jsonObj = [] , i get error on this.jsonObj = data , type object is not assignable to type any[].

Comment: Do not provide any value just declare it `jsonObj;` and if you get undefined error in html then add `*ngIf="jsonObject"` in html.

Comment: because `getObjectsJson()` did not defined what class or structure it will return. So it will take as `any` type which cannot be assigned to array type.

Comment: So I should define it or not ? Want to make it like it should be.

Comment: Spare sometime on understanding the typescript. It will help you in the future. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/by-example.html

Answer (score 0):

The service method is asynchronous, so the code inside the subscribe()  (which makes the assignment) executes at some time in the future, when the http call returns. Your log statement is outside of the subscription, so it happens before the assignment. Try putting the log statement inside the subscription, right after the assignment.

Comment: still empty :) thats not the problem I think

Answer (score 0):

console.log(this.jsonObj) will run before the response of the server. You can work with it as it is. It will run perfectly. you can test it like this

```
<p *ngIf="jsonObj !== undefined">{{jsonObj.field}}</p>
```

if you want to check it with console.log, just add it in the subscription like this

```
this.http.getObjectsJson().subscribe((data => {
      this.jsonObj = data
      console.log(this.jsonObj)
    }));"
```